# Django - creating and saving multiple object in a loop, with ForeignKeys

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am having trouble creating and saving objects in Django. I am very new to Django so I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious!

I am building a price comparison app, and I have a Search model:

`Search` - all searches carried out, recording best price, worst price, product searched for, time of search etc. I have successfully managed to save these searches to a DB and am happy with this model.

The two new models I am working with are:

`Result` - this is intended to record all search results returned, for each search carried out. I.e. Seller 1 £100, Seller 2 £200, Seller 3, £300. (One search has many search results).

'Agent' - a simple table of Agents that I compare prices at. (One Agent can have many search Results).

```
class Agent(models.Model):
   agent_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   agent_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Result(models.Model):
    search_id = models.ForeignKey(Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE)         # Foreign Key of Search table
    agent_id = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)            # Foreign Key of Agent table
    price = models.FloatField()
    search_position = models.IntegerField().
```

My code that is creating and saving the objects is here:

```
def update_search_table(listed, product):
  if len(listed) > 0:
    search = Search(product=product,
                    no_of_agents=len(listed),
                    valid_search=1,
                    best_price=listed[0]['cost'],
                    worst_price=listed[-1]['cost'])

    search.save()

    for i in range(len(listed)):
        agent = Agent.objects.get(agent_name = listed[i]['company'])

        # print(agent.agent_id)           # Prints expected value
        # print(search.search_id)         # Prints expected value
        # print(listed[i]['cost'])        # Prints expected value
        # print(i + 1)                    # Prints expected value

        result = Result(search_id = search,
                        agent_id = agent,
                        price = listed[i]['cost'],
                        position = i + 1)

        search.result_set.add(result)
        agent.result_set.add(result)

        result.save()
```

Up to `search.save()` is working as expected.

The first line of the for loop is also correctly retrieving the relevant Agent.

The rest of it is going wrong (i.e. not saving any Result objects to the Result table). What I want to achieve is, if there are 10 different agent results returned, create 10 `Result` objects and save each one. Link each of those 10 objects to the `Search` that triggered the results, and link each of those 10 objects to the relevant `Agent`.

Have tried quite a few iterations but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't said how the rest of the loop is "going wrong". What exactly happens?

Comment: Hi Daniel, it is going wrong in the sense that I am not seeing my Result table populated with any search results (Search table is fine). I'm not getting any error messages in the console, which doesn't help at all!

Comment: If I put a print statement immediately after my result=Result(), nothing is printed at all, so I think it's this bit that's failing somehow.

Comment: Try saving the result before doing either of the `result_set.add` calls. The result may need to be saved and have an ID before you can create a relation to it.